# How to create a sprite from a folder with and without background-size (using Compass)

Tags: css, compass-sass, css-sprites

I want to use a Compass generated icon-sprite for two different scenarios.

1. Use the icon(s) in original size.
2. Use it the same icon(s) as a smaller version using CSS3 property `background-size`.

I first do this:

```
$logo-spacing: 20px;
@import "logo/*.png";
@include all-logo-sprites;
```

Now I can use the general created CSS-classes like `.logo-twitter` etc.

Two achieve the second result I could use this ([darren131 / gist:3410875 - resize sprites in Compass](https://gist.github.com/3410875)):

```
@mixin resize-sprite($map, $sprite, $percent) {
  $spritePath:    sprite-path($map);
  $spriteWidth:   image-width($spritePath);
  $spriteHeight:  image-height($spritePath);
  $width: image-width(sprite-file($map, $sprite));
  $height: image-height(sprite-file($map, $sprite));

  @include background-size(ceil($spriteWidth * ($percent/100)) ceil($spriteHeight * ($percent/100)));
  width: ceil($width*($percent/100));
  height: ceil($height*($percent/100));
  background-position: 0 floor(nth(sprite-position($map, $sprite), 2)  * ($percent/100) );
}

.my-other-div-with-small-logos {
    .logo-twitter {
        $spriteName: twitter;
        $percentage: 40;

        @include resize-sprite($logo-sprites, $spriteName, $percentage);
    }
}
```

But if I have around 30 logos I would need to repeat this manually for each sprite-class.

Is it possible to import the folder twice, once for the original size and a second time with the `backround-size` property?
Or modify the mentioned method to create all classes automatically within another `<div class="my-other-div-with-small-logos">` where the icons should appear smaller?

Or am I thinking in the wrong direction here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That does it. It iterates over the whole map:

```
@each $sprite in sprite_names($logo-sprites) {
    .logo-#{$sprite} {
        @include resize-sprite($logo-sprites, $sprite, 40);
    }
}
```

This helped: [Way to iterate over sprites in a map](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/1046)

It's great to scale down sprites in modern Browsers without loading another generated sprite-image. If the logos sometimes are 50px, but should also be 20px somewhere else, this is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you all for this. It works! Now, i have gone ahead and expand on it as i needed something a little more dynamic where icons are constructed based on ico-[size] ico-[image] & swatch-[color]

```
$myicons-spacing: 20px;

@import "icons/myicons/*.png";
@include all-myicons-sprites;


@mixin resize-sprite($map, $sprite, $percent) {
  $spritePath    :  sprite-path($map);
  $spriteWidth   :  image-width($spritePath);
  $spriteHeight  :  image-height($spritePath);
  $width         :  image-width(sprite-file($map, $sprite));
  $height        :  image-height(sprite-file($map, $sprite));

  @include background-size(ceil($spriteWidth * ($percent/100)) ceil($spriteHeight * ($percent/100)));

  width                :  ceil($width*($percent/100));
  height               :  ceil($height*($percent/100));
  background-position  :  0 floor(nth(sprite-position($map, $sprite), 2)  * ($percent/100) );
}

@each $sprite in sprite_names($myicons-sprites) {
  .ico-xsmall.myicons-#{$sprite} {
    @extend .myicons-#{$sprite};
    @include resize-sprite($myicons-sprites, $sprite, 35);
  }

  .ico-small.myicons-#{$sprite} {
    @extend .myicons-#{$sprite};
    @include resize-sprite($myicons-sprites, $sprite, 50);
  }

  .ico-medium.myicons-#{$sprite} {
    @extend .myicons-#{$sprite};
    @include resize-sprite($myicons-sprites, $sprite, 87.5);
  }

  .ico-large.myicons-#{$sprite} {
    @extend .myicons-#{$sprite};
    @include resize-sprite($myicons-sprites, $sprite, 100);
  }
}
```

Comment: how can we rewrite the function to use px instead of % : I need my icon do a specific px size, not a percent of the original. 

`@mixin resize-sprite($map, $sprite, $px_size)` like that

Answer (score 1):

Create placeholders for each in a loop and then include the placeholder wherever you need. For example:

```
@mixin resize-sprite($map, $sprite, $percent) {
  $spritePath:    sprite-path($map);
  $spriteWidth:   image-width($spritePath);
  $spriteHeight:  image-height($spritePath);
  $width: image-width(sprite-file($map, $sprite));
  $height: image-height(sprite-file($map, $sprite));

  @include background-size(ceil($spriteWidth * ($percent/100)) ceil($spriteHeight * ($percent/100)));
  width: ceil($width*($percent/100));
  height: ceil($height*($percent/100));
  background-position: 0 floor(nth(sprite-position($map, $sprite), 2)  * ($percent/100) );
}

@each $image in twitter, facebook, pinterest {
  %logo-#{$image} {
    @include resize-sprite($logo-sprites, $image, 40);
  }
}

.my-other-div-with-small-logos {
    .logo-twitter {
        @extend %logo-twitter;
    }
}
```

Note that this assumes all images should be resized by 40%. You'll need to do more creative iterating if you need to specify different percentages for different logos.

Better yet, maybe just generate the classes in the loop?

```
.my-other-div-with-small-logos {
  @each $image in twitter, facebook, pinterest {
    .logo-#{$image} {
      @include resize-sprite($logo-sprites, $image, 40);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it somehow possible to get all the needed classes from the sprite-map itself to have a fully generated loop?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, though you could surely extend compass to do this if you really wanted to. But there's something to be said for having it explicit in the sass so you can reference it explicitly, search for it, etc.

Comment: I guess that's my biggest problem. I went through the Compass spriting-manual, but don't get it. I'll have a look again.

Comment: how can we rewrite the function to use px instead of % : I need my icon do a specific px size, not a percent of the original